# Luigi task fails on main "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Tags: python, json, macos, python-2.7, luigi

I only receive this error when I run the task without --local-scheduler, on OS X El Cap. Daemon created with `luigid` command is currently running as well.

When I run the task with --local-scheduler, it operates as expected. It also runs fine both with and without --local-scheduler on my Windows 7 vm. Curious as to why it only fails in that one case on OS X.

Code snippet comes from this post I was referencing begin learning Luigi:https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/10/24/building-data-pipelines-with-python-and-luigi/

Code:

```
import luigi


class PrintNumbers(luigi.Task):
    n = luigi.IntParameter()

    def requires(self):
        return []

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("numbers_up_to_{}.txt".format(self.n))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as f:
            for i in range(1, self.n+1):
                f.write("{}\n".format(i))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run()
```

The trace:

**File "scrape.py", line 24, in 
    luigi.run()**

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 210, in run
    return _run(*args, **kwargs)['success']

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 238, in _run
    return _schedule_and_run([cp.get_task_obj()], worker_scheduler_factory)

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/interface.py", line 194, in _schedule_and_run
    success &= worker.add(t, env_params.parallel_scheduling)

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 565, in add
    for next in self._add(item, is_complete):

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 682, in _add
    retry_policy_dict=_get_retry_policy_dict(task),

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 441, in _add_task
    self._scheduler.add_task(*args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/scheduler.py", line 112, in rpc_func
    return self._request('/api/{}'.format(fn_name), actual_args, **request_args)

File "/Users/-/.virtualenvs/adwords/lib/python2.7/site-packages/luigi/rpc.py", line 145, in _request
    response = json.loads(page)["response"]

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

**File 
"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded**

Comment: do you have an scheduler instance running? notice that the task you're running is trying to reach that scheduler: its default address is http://localhost:8082. If you're running -say- nginx it must be giving you a forbidden response (html), that's why your task fails to run.

Comment: Isn't that what the luigid command creates? If so, yes, I have the global scheduler running. I then load up the URL in chrome to look at the dashboard.

Comment: yes, right ...then you should be able to look into luigid log files if there's any error. Also you may see the which endpoints are being requested in console output.

Comment: I have a theory...whenever I install luigi in a venv on OS X, I have an xcode install asking me to download `clang`. Since the firewall i'm behind wont allow me to install xcode or anything affiliated...I think that is my issue with the OS X side deamon not working, where on my windows VM I have pretty much free reign.